# How to install TCL package textutil, tdom and udp?

Tags: linux, package, tcl, package-managers

./Tcltest.tcl
I am having trouble executing the TCL script in my test environment.

```
Sourcing files.
INIT : ERROR while sourcing
can't find package textutil
```

The file also contains

```
package require textutil
package require tdom
package require udp
```

Please help.

Comment: This will help in your case . [Click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927150/how-to-install-tcl-packages-uuid-itcl-html-tdom-tdom-tepam-mathbignum)

Comment: What's your distribution? Do you use apt or yum or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu you would want

```
sudo apt install tcllib tdom tcl-udp
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

> Using `yum` command

Then try the following:

`sudo yum install tcllib tdom tcludp`

> Working on Linux x86_64

This is not particularly illuminating, an answer would be one of Centos, Scientific Linux, Fedora, RHEL, ... depending on the answer, additional steps will be required.